# How to remove hidden newline or carriage return character in vim

Tags: vim

I have a CSV file on macOS that was created by Windows that looks like this:

```
"C00115940","","","","","O","","","f","","b",NULL,"92583","","123-456-7890","","","","","","M","W","","","","jc@abc.def","","","","C","5","","S",NULL,"92583","","951","","","m@s.gov","","","","","","","","","",NULL,NULL,"",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"",NULL,NULL,"",NULL,NULL,"",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"",NULL,NULL,"",""," ","1","",NULL,"","","","","",NULL,"","75350","","","",NULL,"","","","","","","","","","",""¬
"C00102747","","","","","R","","","3","","A",NULL,"12207","","5","","","","","","S","D","","","","t@abc.def","","","","R","35 Any St¬
3rd Fl","","A",NULL,"12207","","5","","","S@r.org","","","","","","","","","",NULL,NULL,"",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"",NULL,NULL,"",NULL,NULL,"",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"",NULL,NULL,"",""," T","1","",NULL,"","","","","",NULL,"","75350","","","",NULL,"","","","","","","","","","",""¬
```

In vim, I have `:set list` enabled so you can see `¬` where the newlines are.

On the second line I have a newline in the middle of one of the fields that I need to remove.  Every line should always end in a double-quote. If I do `/[^"]$` I can see, for example, `t¬` on the second line where the newline is inside the address field (`"35 Any St¬ 3rd Fl"`)

I have tried `:%s/\([^"]\)$/\1/g` but that doesn't do anything.

Is there a better substitution command I can run that will remove these bad newlines but not any of the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close! You can use `\n` to match a new line in vim's search command, so
you can highlight problematic lines with:

```
/[^"]\n
```

You could join them like so:

```
:%s/\([^"]\)\n/\1/g
```

or in a slightly more elegant way using a global command:

```
:g/[^"]\n/join
```

or equivalently:

```
:g/[^"]\n/normal J
```